# NestJs GRPC - How to set up a grpc client interceptor while using nestjs

Tags: authentication, microservices, grpc, interceptor, nestjs

when using grpc with nestjs, is there any way to set up a grpc interceptor for client ?.

My use case is

> set authorization header for every outgoing request from one
>   microservice to another without writing code to set header each time.

Currently, I'm setting the authorization header in metadata each time I make a grpc service call. It would be much better if I have a common place to handle these genric requirements.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i am looking to do the same thing but i do not see a way to set an interceptor